# How does the scanning effect in Bejeweled 2/3 be implemented?

Tags: iphone, effect

Has anyone who had played the game Bejeweled 2 or Bejeweled 3 on iPhone or on PC noticed the 'scanning effect' on gems? The effect is like a passing light scanning from top left to right bottom. I want to know how it was implemented. Can anyone give a hint? Which technology would be required on iOS platform?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to write a shader for that effect, see this question: [How can I modify the shader in the iPhone OpenGL ES template to produce this effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965941/how-can-i-modify-the-shader-in-the-iphone-opengl-es-template-to-produce-this-effe) the same kind of effect is created there.